# How does the forward and reverse system work on the IH International 845 tractor?

Tags: transmission, tractor

It's not broken, I'm only interested how it works.
Pressing the clutch is not needed to operate this handle. It can also take a few seconds before it starts moving.
[image: The red handle]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: 2nd comment - it's basically an auto box...

Comment: Not sure, but it has manual gears and in some gears pulling the handle backwards will make it go faster. (look at the little arrows)

Comment: Could it by a hydraulic drive?

Comment: I don't think so because it feels like you would be able to stall the engine if you start it in a gear that's to high.

Answer (score 1):

The International I drove had a clutchless change between 1-2 then 3-4 and 5-6 , this was done with electro-hydraulic clutch packs.

When they changed the clutch they put the low p sensor wire on the high sensor and vice versa - took a while to sort that!